# Storing elements on click with HTML/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

so Im a noob at html css and javascript, so I this is probably a really obvious question that would be easy to find the answer to with google. Alas, I dont really know where/how to look up what I want, so any tips on finding out how to do specific tasks would be appreciated

Basically, I want to know how to give the users an option to click on a word on a list (or something like a star icon beside the word) so that the word/element can be stored in a "favorites" tab.

Sorry again Im really bad at this.

Comment: This is not an appropriate question to post here. Google is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basicaly you want to get the text of the element and add it in a array.
Like this :

html

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="scan">
      <span>1</span>
      <span>2</span>
      <span>3</span>
      <span>4</span>
    </div>
    <span id="needText">tralala</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript :

```
var array = [];
var textSolo = document.getElementById('needText');
var scan = document.getElementById('scan');

textSolo.onclick = function(){getClick(event)};
scan.onclick = function(){getClick(event)}

function getClick(text){
    array.push(text.target.textContent);
}
```